# Is there a way to isolate the view of code-regions in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have some static HTML and want to generate templates out of it. Looking through the HTML tags I often find myself adding the tags I don't want to have in my templates because I went too far down in the hierarchy. Is there a way to kind of isolate the view of a marked code area? Like greying all unmarked code out somehow?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a "marked" code area? And when you say "generate templates", are you referring to IDEA live templates or File templates? Or something else?

Comment: Sorry. The templates I'm talking about are JSP templates. Just wanted to give a use case scenario. I mean marking like marking code in the editor. I'd like to have an isolated view onto marked code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not 100% sure what you mean by "mark". I'm assuming you mean "select", that is highlight with the cursor, like this:

[image: HTML Code with portion selected]

If that is the case... here is some info.

There is no way to "highlight" the selected portion and work with it, nor a way "dither out" the non selected portion as you go  on to work with the desired portion. You could, however, make use of scratch files to work on the desired text. ([Scratch files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/scratches.html) at IntelliJ IDEA help documentation)

With the portion you want to modify selected, if you create a new scratch file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> / <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> or *Tools > New Scratch File*), the selected portion will be copied into a scratch file:

[image: Scratch File]

You could then work in that scratch file, then copy and paste the final result back into the original file (the changes you make in the scratch file are not "linked" to the original file).

Because you have a portion selected when you launch the scratch file, IDEA creates a scratch file of the same type (HTML in this case) as the selected content. (If done without selected text, a popup is shown asking the type of scratch file you want to create.) If you want JSP syntax awareness, in the HTML scratch file, open the context menu (i.e. right click) and select "Change Language" and select JSP from the menu (inline search is available, so you can just start typing JSP).

Comment: Yea I was using scratchfiles as a workaround for that